# Java print distinct numbers using array and decomposition

Tags: java, arrays, printing, numbers, distinct

If anybody can look over my code, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am almost getting the output that I'm looking for but now quite there, and I'm having a hard time picking it apart looking at it for so long.
I believe it may have something to do with my count code, is the array[i] correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variables
    int[] array=new int[10];

    //Object Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt user
    System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i]=input.nextInt();
    }

    //Sort Array
    Arrays.sort(array);     

    //Count number of distincts
    int count =0 ;
    for(int i=0; i<array[i]; i++){

        count++;

    System.out.print("The number of distinct numbers is " + count);

    }

    //Display distinct numbers
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("The distinct numbers are ");
    for(int i=0; i<array[i]; i++){
        if(array[i] != -1){
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(distinctNumbers(array)));
        }
    }
}

public static int[] distinctNumbers(int[] array){
     int[] distinctNumbers=new int[10];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            for(int j= i+1; j<array.length; j++){
            if(array[i] ==array[j]){
                    array[i]= -1;

            }
            }
        }
        return array;       
    }
}
```

The output that I get currently is:

```
Enter ten numbers: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4

The number of distinct numbers is 1 

The distinct numbers are [-1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, 4]
```

Desired output:

```
Enter ten numbers: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4

The number of distinct numbers is 4

The distinct numbers are [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What do you want as a output??

Comment: @famousDaves desired result is  1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: The number of distinct number is 4
The distinct numbers are 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 places where the mistake might be :

```
System.out.print("The distinct numbers are ");
for(int i=0; i<array[i]; i++){
    if(array[i] != -1){      
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(distinctNumbers(array)));
    }
}
```

Here you check upto array[i] and print the entire array. I think you should check upto array.length and print the array elementwise.My suggested code will be :

```
System.out.print("The distinct numbers are ");
array=distinctNumbers(array);         //operate on the array outside loop
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){           //iterate till array length
    if(array[i] != -1){      
    System.out.print(array[i]+" ");      //print element wise
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that as well and still did not  get the correct input. I put your code through with the print element wise but it was a blank output. Im not sure why it wont take the -1 away. The if statement theoretically shouldved done that..

Comment: @famousDaves You can also see that to count the distinct numbers i have added a bit of modificaion.See the output

Comment: awesome! thanks for the help. it looked like alot of my coding was out of place as well, will definitely pay closer attention to that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(int i=0; i<array[i]; i++){

          count++;

     System.out.print("The number of distinct       numbers is " + count);

     }
```

I think its wrong..  you need to work until array.length .. and then find distinct number .. that why count return 1 instead of 4

And then in display them use if condition like :if(array[i] != -1)

Comment: array.length i put that input earlier as well.. all that does is it goes through the loop showing the output repeating itself.

Comment: Enter ten numbers: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
The number of distinct numbers is 1The number of distinct numbers is 2The number of distinct numbers is 3The number of distinct numbers is 4The number of distinct numbers is 5The number of distinct numbers is 6The number of distinct numbers is 7The number of distinct numbers is 8The number of distinct numbers is 9The number of distinct numbers is 10 
The distinct numbers are [-1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, 4]

Comment: it printed 10 times because you print inside the for loop   use :   int arr=distinctNumbers(array); int count =0 ;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        If(arr[i]!=-1){count++;}// to count only distinct numbers
    }   then print them : System.out.print("The number of distinct numbers is " + count);

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to eliminate duplicates:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = new int[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        array = distinctNumbers(array);

        System.out.println("The number of distinct numbers is: " +
                array.length);

        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
        for(int number : array) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }

        input.close();
    }

    public static int[] distinctNumbers(int[] array) {

        HashSet<Integer> distinctSet = new HashSet<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            distinctSet.add(array[i]);
        }

        int[] distinctArr = new int[distinctSet.size()];
        int j = 0;
        for(Integer number : distinctSet) {
            distinctArr[j++] = number;
        }

        return distinctArr;
    }
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
Enter ten numbers: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
The number of distinct numbers is: 4
The distinct numbers are: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: oh lawd lol.. the display couldnt have been that easy to miss.. do you know of another way to get the distinct numbers without using the hashset? ive never heard of it before.

Comment: @famousDaves Not sure what you mean by "the display couldn't have been that easy to miss"? Sure, you could do it without a hashset..

Comment: lol. i mean, i cant believe i just didnt try to output it using that in the first place..

Comment: thanks for the help! will definitley look into using hashset for coding, looks like it saves alot of time and headache. lol

Comment: @famousDaves no problem! Unless stated otherwise, making use of built-in data structures isn't such a bad idea.